# Functions: changing variable from int to float

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am taking my first python course, this should be an easy thing but I can't get it right. I have done a search, but I guess the keyword are just too common.

So, I did an assignment where I had to write a function that squares a number. I did it successfully with just:

```
def square(x):
    '''x: int or float.'''
    return x * x
```

I have tried with other functions just to try different ways of doing the exercise, if I try to incorporate some loop like:

```
def square(x):
    '''x: int or float.'''
    for number in range(x):
        result = x * x
    return result
```

It only works for integers(so square(5) gives me 25, but square (5.0) gives me 'TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float'. How can I get this function to square floats or negative numbers? Thanks in advance

Comment: `for number in range(int(x)):`

Comment: what do you want to do in your 2nd code snippet?

Comment: What do you actually want to do? What do you want `square(0.5)` to return?

Comment: @ndpu How can you tell that is what is needed? It doesn't convert from `int` to `float` as per the question title. The question is rather unclear.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, subject is incorrect i think, im comment for this error 'TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float'

Comment: Your loop doesn't actually do anything: it overwrites the value of `result` every time with the same number, and doesn't even use `number`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First question

`It's only valid for integers(so square(5) gives me 25, but square (5.0) gives me 'TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float'.`

### Answer

Because `range` function is defined as taking only integer data. See [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=range#range).

Example:

```
>>> range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> range(5.0)
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.

>>> range("5")
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str.

>>> range(0, 5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> range(0, 5.0)
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.
```

### Second question

`How can I get this valid for floats or negative numbers?`

### Answer

I don't know what "valid" means. It depends on what you are trying to do. So please comment or update your question.

Comment: Thanks, made it more precise now. What I meant is how to obtain square of floats using that function.
So then, it doesn't make sense to use range at all when you want to operate with floats?

Comment: Yes you don't need to use `range` unless you want to do loop operation or treat list(vector) data. And if you want a list of float, you can write a code like `map(float,range(5))`. So to create 0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,, list, you can use `range` and `float`.

Answer (score 0):

The loop in your second example doesn't actually do anything: it overwrites the value of `result` every time with the same number, and doesn't even use the loop counter.

If you want an alternate way to compute a square, a method for integers only that uses loops would be this:

```
def square2(x):
        x = int(math.fabs(x))
        result = 0
        for i in range(x):
                result += x
        return result
```

This takes the sum of `x` added together `x` times (i.e., converts the multiplication into addition). It handles negative integers as well, but not floats. The reason this doesn't work for floats is that you can't count from 0 to an arbitrary float (real numbers are uncountable).

Honestly, your first solution in your question is the straightforward, simple, and therefore (IMO) the best one.